# Some test cases aren't passing

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int i=0;  //points at the current stack that we are working with
int box=0; //no. of boxes held by the crane
int64_t H; //max. height of the stacks given in the que.



int main()
{
   int n, value; //storing no. of stacks and creating an additional variable value to store operations

    std::cin>> n >> H;

    int64_t arr[n]; //storing the no. of boxes each stack has in an array

    std::vector<int> arr2;  //storing the operations we have to perform in a vector


   for(int j=0; j<n; j++){std::cin>> arr[j];} //getting arr

   while(std::cin>>value) //getting arr2
    {
        arr2.push_back(value);
    }



    for(int xy=0; xy<n; xy++){if(arr[xy]>H){return 0;}} //ensuring that all stacks have no.of boxes less than max. height 

if(arr2.size()<1 || arr2.size()>10e5 ||  n<1 || n>10e5 || H<1 || H>10e8){return 0;} //constraints given in the que.

   int k=0; //creating a variable to keep count of how many programs we have already executed
  while(k<arr2.size()){

    if(arr2[k] == 1){MoveLeft();}

    else if(arr2[k]==2){MoveRight(n);}

    else if(arr2[k]==3){PickBox(arr, i);}
    else if(arr2[k]==4){Dropbox(arr, i);}
    else if(arr2[k]==0){k=arr2.size();}

       k++;

 }

    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){std::cout<< arr[j] << " ";} //printing the arr after executing the code

return 0;

}
```

[This](https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO14001) is a question from a past year ZCO. And the above code is what I wrote to solve the prob.

The four functions Moveleft, MoveRight, Pickbox, Dropbox have been defined in the same file but aren't shown here because I think there's no issue with them.

When I [submit](https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/submit/ZCO14001) the code, all test cases passed except 2. I don't know what is the problem with my code. Pls help me.

I have tried my best to make the code readable. Sorry if the code looks messy.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with expected inputs and outputs and actual outputs. Please also explain what the code is supposed to do without relying on links to external sites

Comment: `int64_t arr[n]` isn't valid c++, use `std::vector` instead

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks. I will try that. I will also edit my question to make it more readable in a few minutes.

Comment: please include a [mcve]. If Moveleft, MoveRight, Pickbox and Dropbox are not needed to reproduce the problem then write an example without them that does reproduce the problem including input, output and expected output. The error is **always** in a place where you do not expect it, otherwise you would have fixed it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the method you're trying to define an array with a user-input length is unfortunately invalid in C++.

But fortunately, there are basically two methods use to allocate arrays dynamically.

**Method 1: Using Vectors**

Vector is an important part of C++. It has a lot of features (e.g. its size don't need to be defined static unlike a normal array does, can redefine array size, etc.) An example's given:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> vArray; // vector<> declaration
    int size = 0;
    int getInput = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter an array size: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter a value: ";
        std::cin >> getInput;

        vArray.push_back(getInput); // inserts one+ container and data in it
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vArray.size(); i++) {
        // retrieving contained data...
        std::cout << vArray[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Method 2: Using 'new' Keyword with Pointed Variable**

The simple use of `new` will help you to achieve your requirement. It's less recommended since already there's concept of vectors which actually works efficiently than arrays. Let's take a look into a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int *pArray;
    int size;

    std::cout << "Enter an array size: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    pArray = new int[size]; // initializing array with dynamic size

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter value: ";
        std::cin >> pArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << pArray[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] pArray;

    return 0;
}
```

Both are nice options to work with, but it's recommended by most using `vector<>`.